# Update record in observableArray when user submits, not automatically, with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an observableArray that is rendered in a grid. When the user clicks a row a dialog form pops up giving the user the ability to edit the selected item.  I'd like to give the user the ability to update or cancel their changes, but since the selected record is an observable the changes are made immediately.

How can I separate the selected record from the observableArray so the data is only updated when the user clicks 'Update'?

Here is a simplified version of my problem - my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bflemi3/TWMZc/)

```
function Type(data) {
    this.id = data.id;
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};

function Location(data) {
    this.id = data.id;
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.state = ko.observable(data.state);
    this.headline = ko.observable(data.headline);
    this.type = ko.observable(new Type(data.type));
};

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.types = types;
    self.locations = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(seedData, function(item) {
        return new Location(item);
    }));
    self.selectedLocation = ko.observable();

    self.edit = function(item) {
        self.selectedLocation(item);
    };

    self.cancel = function() {
        self.selectedLocation(null);
    };

    self.update = function(item) {
        //do something here to push updated Location to locations observableArray
    };
}
```

Comment: You should understand that your `selectedLocation` observable will contain **actual** location item and all edits you made will be reflected on same instance. It is because objects in JS are assigned by reference, not by value. Read about *editor* pattern implemetation here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your structure matches up pretty well with the type of editor pattern that I described in the article linked in the comment above: http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html

For your data, this would mean tracking a `selectedItem` and a `selectedItemForEditing` that is a new `Location` created using the data of the selected item.

If the user cancels, then you can just throw it away.  If the user accepts, then you can take the edited item's data and apply it to the original selected item.

The article describes separating the creation of observables with populating them with data, so that you can always call an `update` method with clean data to apply.

Here is your fiddle updated with these techniques: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/JQkVs/

Comment: What if the `types` array we're out of scope to the `Location` object. How would you update the `type` property with the appropriate `name`? http://jsfiddle.net/bflemi3/JQkVs/4/

Comment: I would personally do it like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/kMNkY/. This simplifies a few things and makes sure that we are always dealing with a reference to the same "type" object. I don't use the `optionsValue` binding, so that it just sets type to the object.